# Kotlin Kovenant returns the same object for all promises

Tags: kotlin, kovenant

I'm trying to use Kotlin Kovenant because I want a promise-based solution to track my retrofit calls.

What I did first was this:

```
    all (
        walkingRoutePromise,
        drivingRoutePromise
    ) success { responses ->
        //Do stuff with the list of responses
    }
```

where the promises I pass are those that are resolved at the completion of my retrofit calls. However "responses" is a list of two identical objects. When debugging, I can confirm that two different objects with different values are being passed to the respective resolve methods. However kovenant returns two identical objects (same location in memory)

My next attempt was this:

```
    task {
        walkingRoutePromise
    } then {
        var returnval = it.get()
        walkingDTO = returnval.deepCopy()
        drivingRoutePromise
    } success {
        val returnval = it.get()
        drivingDTO = returnval.deepCopy()
        mapRoutes = MapRoutes(walkingDTO!!, drivingDTO!!)
        currentRoute = mapRoutes!!.walking
        callback()
    }
```

Where I tried to do the calls one at a time and perform deep copies of the results. This worked for the first response, but then I found that it.get() in the success block - the success block of the second call - is the same unchanged object that I get from it.get() in the "then" block. It seems Kovenant is implemented to use one object for all of its resolutions, but after you resolve once, the single object it uses for the resolutions cannot be changed. What am I supposed to do if I want to access unique values from promise.resolve(object)? Seems like a very broken system.